# Unable to add a couple rows heading rows to data for pdf

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am able to generate pdf with jspdf-autotable but I am unable to create a heading row. for the data. I tried rowStyles { colspan: 3} but that did'nt work and from the docs it's not clear to me how this can be done. For example, I have rows of data like this:

```
[item, item2, item3]
 ...
 ...
[item, item2, item3]
```

How can I add a heading row so it looks like this:

```
[     heading1     ]
[     heading2     ]
[item, item2, item3]
 ...
 ...
[item, item2, item3]
```

This is how I am creating the pdf:

```
        window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

        var doc = new jsPDF("p");
        doc.setFontSize(8);
        var y = 10;
        // set midPage
        var midPage = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() / 2;
        doc.setLineWidth(2);

        let wantedTableWidth = 160;
        let pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
        let margin = (pageWidth - wantedTableWidth) / 2;

        var txt = "Test page title"

        doc.text(txt, midPage - 2, y, "center");
        doc.autoTable({
            body: data[0],
            margin: { left: margin + 38, right: margin + 38 },
            tableLineColor: [255, 255, 255],
            startY: 32,
            theme: "grid",
            styles: {
                halign: "center",
                cellPadding: 1,
                minCellHeight: 5,
                fontSize: 8,
            },
            headStyles: { fillColor: [0, 125, 255] },
            alternateRowStyles: { fillColor: [220, 220, 220] },
            tableLineColor: [173, 216, 230],
            tableLineWidth: 0.1,
            columnStyles: {
                0: { valign: "middle", halign: "center", cellWidth: 20 },
                1: { valign: "middle", halign: "right", cellWidth: 20 },
                2: { valign: "middle", halign: "right", cellWidth: 22 },
                3: { valign: "middle", halign: "right", cellWidth: 22 }
            },
            header: ['Grade 15']
        });

        doc.text(
            "Footer text",
            midPage - 2,
            doc.internal.pageSize.height - 20,
            "center"
        );
```

Thank you.